# Kafka consumer not get message when polling

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use kafka consumer to register the kafka, but it didn't get any message when polling. Anyone can tell me why or where to look at the log?
listTopics = patientorders1, sapconsignment_temps, appointmentschedules
kafka consumer configuration

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConfiguration.getClientId());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, grpId);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "50000000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "50000000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

        kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(listTopics);
```

snippet of polling code

```
           while (true) {


            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
            String strKafkaTimeStamp = "";
            LOGGER.info("#---------------------- START LOOPING ------------------------#");
            Long startOffset = 0L;
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                if (startOffset == 0L){
                    startOffset = record.offset();
                    LOGGER.info("Offset = {} size = {}", startOffset.toString(), records.count());
                }}
```

[image]

Comment: please add a more detailed image which contains also consumer groups name and code sample of your consumer.

Comment: updated more detail. by the way, after changing the config MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG and FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG from 700000000 to 500000000, it works, somehow. Anyone know the maximum values of these 2 parameters we can set?

Comment: [Here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.partition.fetch.bytes) you can find more details about this parameters, because they are `int` I guess `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum allowed.

Comment: As per your information, both values should work. I also notice the higher values I set, The higher number of no records from polling. for example, when I set the value to 50000000, consumers poll about 10 times to get messages. the first 9 times have no message and I got about 14 messages.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple consumers in the same group? Since you only have one partition on 3 topics, then maybe another consumer is currently assigned those partitions. Then when you start another consumer, it will rebalance, and you get distributed consumption (i.e. not all records).